# Replace 500 random elements in an array from 0 to 1

Tags: python, numpy, random

Numpy: Replace 500 random elements in an array from 0 to 1

```
import numpy as np
import random

# 2D Grid world of 100 x 100 cells
arr = np.zeros((100,100))

# Arbitrarily change 500 elements from 0 to 1 
for
```

Comment: I want to create a 2D grid world of 1000 x 1000 cells and have arbitrarily chosen 500 of the cells to represent an obstacle

Answer (score 2):

You can select 500 random unique numbers between 0 and 100*100 to index your array as 1D and assign 1:

```
import numpy as np

# 2D Grid world of 100 x 100 cells
arr = np.zeros((100,100))

arr.flat[np.random.choice(np.arange(arr.size), 500, replace=False)] = 1
```

Example with 10 random 1s in a 10x10 array:

```
arr = np.zeros((10,10), dtype=int)

arr.flat[np.random.choice(np.arange(arr.size), 10, replace=False)] = 1

print(arr)
```

Output:

```
[[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0]]
```

Same output with 0/1 shown as □/■ for better visualization:

```
[[□ □ ■ □ □ □ □ □ □ □]
 [□ □ □ □ □ □ ■ □ □ □]
 [□ □ □ □ □ □ ■ □ □ □]
 [□ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □]
 [□ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □]
 [□ □ □ □ ■ ■ □ □ □ □]
 [□ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □ □]
 [□ □ □ ■ □ ■ □ □ □ □]
 [□ □ □ □ □ □ ■ □ □ □]
 [□ □ □ ■ □ ■ □ □ □ □]]
```